# functools.wraps returning a __dict__ of type dict instead of type mappingproxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, functools

This is my first question here, after a long time consulting. I have googled about this issue a lot and I think I did not find any useful information addressing it.

I am trying to create a general deprecation python decorator for my code in Python 3. The objective is to correctly wrap a function or class doing two things: print a warning about deprecation, and prepend the `__doc__` with deprecation information (that it can be processed also by `sphinx`). I think I have sorted out most of what I wanted, I'm still struggling with Sphinx, but I found something curious about the behaviour of `functools.wraps`. Basically, the `__dict__` of a wrapped class is of type `dict` while in an unwrapped class has type `mappingproxy`.

Here is some showcase code:

```
import functools

class Deprecated(object):
    def __call__(self, cls):
        myassigns = functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS
        myassigns += ('__mro__',)

        @functools.wraps(cls, assigned=myassigns)
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            warnings.warn(message, category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_func


@Deprecated()
class SomeOldClass:
    def some_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y

print(type(SomeOldClass.__dict__))
print(type(SomeClass.__dict__))
```

And the output:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'mappingproxy'>
```

Is the `functools.wraps` misbehaving or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your "wrapped class" is a function. What did you expect `functools.wraps` to do?

Comment: Did you mean to wrap `some_method`? Because as is, you wrapped the class itself, which sort of works (haven't looked deeply, but I believe it should warn when you create an instance), but it also means that the name refers to the wrapper function, not the class anymore, so no class related stuff is visible on `SomeOldClass` without explicitly drilling through to `__wrapped__` attribute. If you want to deprecate classes this way, your wrapper should drill into the class and wrap `__init__` or `__new__` explicitly (returning the original `cls`), not return a function wrapping a class.

Comment: @user2357112 I expect it to mask my wrapping function, so that is appears has it is the original class, except for my changes. Concretely, I wanted functions like `help()` to work properly on my deprecated Class.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for your feedback! I can try to wrap the `__init__`, didn't think about that. The problem with that approach is that I cannot easily prepend the `__doc__`, can I?

Comment: @j3mdamas: If you wrap the class itself, you can modify its doc, then explicitly wrap its `__init__` and reassign it. You still return the original `cls` you were passed, you're just changing attributes on it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that would be awesome, and would solve my question, as a correctly wrapped class would have the correct type in `__dict__`. Can you give me an example? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "I expect it to mask my wrapping function, so that is appears has it is the original class, except for my changes" - `functools.wraps` can only make a function look like another function, and even that has its limitations. It's not going to make a function look like a class. There are much less subtle ways in which things will go wrong than just `__dict__` having an unexpected type; for example, subclassing and `isinstance` will be completely broken.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct. Maybe my initial question should have been about decorating Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest making your wrapper class aware, so it doesn't wrap the class itself:

```
class Deprecated(object):
    def __init__(self, messagefmt='{wrapped} is deprecated'):
        self.messagefmt = messagefmt

    def __call__(self, wrapped):
        message = self.messagefmt.format(wrapped=wrapped.__name__)
        wrappingclass = isinstance(wrapped, type)
        if wrappingclass:
            wrappedfunc = wrapped.__init__
        else:
            wrappedfunc = wrapped

        @functools.wraps(wrappedfunc)
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            warnings.warn(message, category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            return wrappedfunc(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped.__doc__ = 'Deprecated\n\n' + message + '\n\n' + (wrapped.__doc__ or '')

        if wrappingclass:
            wrapped.__init__ = new_func
            return wrapped
        else:
            return new_func
```

This lets you use it with both classes:

```
 @Deprecated()
 class SomeOldClass:
     def some_method(self, x, y):
         return x + y
```

without obscuring the class behaviors and with functions (possibly with a custom deprecation message):

```
 @Deprecated('foo is dead')
 def foo():
     pass
```

So when you use them:

```
 >>> import warnings
 >>> warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=DeprecationWarning)
 >>> SomeOldClass()
 /usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: SomeOldClass is deprecated
   #!/usr/bin/python3
 <__main__.SomeOldClass at 0x7fea8f744a20>
 >>> foo()
 /usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: foo is dead
   #!/usr/bin/python3
```

And similarly, the `__doc__` for both is modified to prepend the deprecation notice (you can tweak it to Sphinxify it, I was just providing basic example).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the answer that I was looking for! I am going to test it, but I'm sure it works.

Comment: @j3mdamas: I tested it on the cases shown (and made sure it can properly modified the `__doc__` strings, that the `class` remained a class, etc.), but I'm sure there are some edge cases (for example, my test for class vs. non-class is not old-style class friendly on Py2, so you'd need to tweak it a bit to support old-style classes). Regardless, it should be fairly close, with minimal tweaking needed.

Comment: Just a small comment: for methods, the `__doc__` wasn't being updated. I moved the assignment to before `@functools.wraps(wrappedfunc)` and it started working.

Comment: Just a final comment: Thank you a lot for your example. Works perfectly and I hope that anyone trying to decorate a class finds this answer. I don't need compatibility with Py2, so I'm good. About the Sphinx, my problem was due to the fact that the wrapper turned the class into a function. Since your code solves that, all my problems with Sphinx got solved :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`functools.wrap` isn't misbehaving nor are you technically doing something wrong, you've returned the function which *when called* will return the instance.

After wrapping, `SomeOldClass` is the function `new_func` you wrapped and returned:

```
>>> SomeOldClass
<function __main__.SomeOldClass>
```

not the class. The un-decorated `SomeClass` is preserved as a class who's `__dict__` is a `mappingproxy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's hard to find working examples of decorated Classes though, so I was going with this approach.